# JQuery not working in IE, but works in Chrome and firefox

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have to develop an application which part of is IQuery but Im not familiar with it.
The code must execute when mousehover on map and change background color piece of map and link color. It works in Chrome and Firefox, but no effect in Inernet Exlporer. 
Any help please !

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
try{
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        $.fn.maphilight.defaults = {
            fill: true,
            fillColor: '008000',
            fillOpacity: 0.8,
            stroke: false,
            strokeColor: 'ff0000',
            strokeOpacity: 1,
            strokeWidth: 1,
            fade: true,
            alwaysOn: false,
            neverOn: false,
            groupBy: false
        };
        $(".main-menu").mouseover(function () {
            alert('go');
            var himg = $(this).attr('himg')
            $(this).children().attr('src', himg)
        });

        $(".main-menu").mouseout(function () {
            var nimg = $(this).attr('nimg')
            $(this).children().attr('src', nimg)
        });

        $("a.fancybox").fancybox({
            'titlePosition': 'inside'
        });

        $("a.iframe").click(function () {
            $.fancybox({
                'padding': 0,
                'margin': 0,
                'autoScale': false,
                'transitionIn': 'none',
                'transitionOut': 'none',
                'width': 980,
                'height': 575,
                'href': this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
                'type': 'iframe'
            })
            return false;
        });

        $('#photos').galleryView({
            panel_width: 900,
            panel_height: 300,
            frame_width: 160,
            frame_height: 110
        }); 
        $("#one").sexyCombo({
            emptyText: "Select"
        });
        $("#two").sexyCombo({
            emptyText: "Select"
        });
        $("#three").sexyCombo({
            emptyText: "Select"
        });

    }); 
    }
catch (err)
 {
    alert(err);
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `try-catch` call. You don't seem to really need that there and is causing the offense in IE.

Comment: Original code is without try-catch, I added this for catching error, but can not catch it. Therefore I think try-catch is not reason.